# Android ListView WebView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

I have a `ListView` where some rows could be `WebView`s. Now I have the problem, that after some scrolling the `WebView`s don't load the URLs. The content of my `WebView` are on the sdcard and I load them with

```
webView.loadUrl("file://PATH/index.html");
```

Is there a problem with multiple instances of `WebView`s in one `ListView`?

My problem is, that I need them all and couldn't remove some. Or could there be a problem because of JScript in my html files?

Comment: can u some code specifically the ListView's adapter?

Comment: The `ListView` adapter created my `WebView` (checked it with the Android Device Monitor), but the URL did not load. The `ListView` adapter is not using any holder, because every row is unique to its content. - Or what are you concerning about?

Comment: try using holder.I think it will work.

Comment: I can't, because the `Layout` are not in XML-layout-files. It's all done be code. It should be a reader app, where the content is completely dynamic, that's why I can't use holders.

Comment: You need to implement "Pagination" for it. It means, load 7-8 items/webview after scrolling down load next 7-8 items/webview. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Pagination is not an option. It should be an "endless" list. I put a log.d() in the finalize function and see that my `WebView` is correctly fetched by the GC, but after a time of scrolling the GC doesn't catch my `WebView`. - I will try it with simple HTML files (without JScript). Maybe the problem is there.